# group different values in one variable together

Tags: sql, group-by

Is it possible to group multiple values in one field together? For example, in Account, they have contract type P, S, O. I need to sum the contract amounts S & O together and leave P by itself.

I have tried:

```sql
select Contract_ID, Case when contract_type in ('S', 'O')then sum(to_char(nvl(contract_amount,0), '000000.99' )) when contract_type = 'P' then sum(to_char(nvl(contract_amount,0), '000000.99' ))End as Contract_Amount

sum (Case when contract_type in ('S', 'O') then to_char(nvl(contract_hours,0), '000000.99')) when contract_type = 'P' then to_char(nvl(contract_hours,0), '000000.99')) End as Contract_Hours

from Contract group by Contract_id Contract_type
```

Comment: Hello @JonesTJ, it would be good if you could edit your question to add sample data and expected output. This would help us providing you with an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  The `case` is the argument to the `sum()`.  Something like this:

```
select Contract_ID,
       sum(Case when contract_type in ('S', 'O') then contract_amount 
           End) as Contract_Amount,
       sum(Case when contract_type in ('S', 'O') then contract_hours
           End) as Contract_hours
from Contract
group by Contract_id;
```

Comment: That will sum them all up together. I need only  O and S sum together.

Comment: @JonesTJ . . . Then remove the `'P'` (as I have done).  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear.
The data look like this:

Contract ID    ContractType Contract Amount Contract Hours
14567  P  200   25
14567  O  100   15
13253  P  300   12
13523  S  150   5
13523  O  500   50
9852  p  200   10


I want the return data to look like this:
Contract ID    Contract Amount Contract Hours
14567  200   25
14567  100   15
13253  300   12
13523  650   55
9852  200   10

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNION for the 2 different cases:

```
select t.* from (
  select ContractID, ContractAmount, ContractHours from Contract c
    where not exists (
      select 1 from Contract where 
        ContractID = c.ContractID and ContractType <> c.ContractType 
        and ContractType in ('O', 'S') and c.ContractType in ('O', 'S')
    )
  union
  select t.ContractID, SUM(t.ContractAmount), SUM(t.ContractHours) from (
    select * from Contract c
    where exists (
      select 1 from Contract where 
        ContractID = c.ContractID and ContractType <> c.ContractType 
        and ContractType in ('O', 'S') and c.ContractType in ('O', 'S')
    )
  ) t
  group by t.ContractID
) t
order by t.ContractID desc
```

Comment: If company 'A' has a contract type P and S, I need two lines in the file that sums P and S. I do not want more than 3 columns.

Comment: The 1st query gets 3 columns: Contract_ID, Contract_Amount and Contract_Hours.

Comment: The first query has five variables in the select statement.

Comment: Which is the 4th?

Comment: As I said the query has **3 columns**: `Contract_ID`, `Contract_Amount` and `Contract_Hours`

Comment: Thanks but that not what I am looking for. The SQL does not account for 'P'.

Comment: In your question you say you want the sum for `'S' and 'O'`. Isn't this right?

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear.
The data look like this:

Contract ID    ContractType Contract Amount Contract Hours
14567  P  200   25
14567  O  100   15
13253  P  300   12
13523  S  150   5
13523  O  500   50
9852  p  200   10


I want the return data to look like this:
Contract ID    Contract Amount Contract Hours
14567  200   25
14567  100   15
13253  300   12
13523  650   55
9852  200   10